# Copy data from non consecutive cells on one worksheet to the next available row on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an order from on a worksheet labeled "Order Form" that is filled by my colleagues for each new order. I need them to click a button and then all the data they have filled in will be copied to another worksheet labeled "Orders".

The best I could get was the data pasted into the same cells on the "Orders" worksheet.

Code for copying.

```vb
Dim copyRng As Range, cel As Range, _
    pasteRng As Range

Set copyRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Order Form").Range("B3,F3,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,D21,D22,D23,D24,D25,D26,D27,D28,D29,D30,D31,D32,D33,D34,E48,D36,G10,C40,G40")
Set pasteRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders").Range("A2")
```

I need to paste the copied data into the next blank row on the "Orders" worksheet.

Comment: Nothing in your posted code does any copying or pasting.

Comment: Probably just need `copyrng.copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders").Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup)(2)`.

Comment: Sorry i may have deleted part of the code when trying to get it working, i need the data in the cells listed to be copied and then pasted to another worksheet. I would be so grateful if you could tell me how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Is your intention to list all these values underneath eachother in a single column?

Comment: No i want them to be along a row on a separate sheet.. Basically the data in the cells listed ("B3,F3,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,D21,D22,D23,D24,D25,D26,D27,D28,D29,D30,D31,D32,D33,D34,E48,D36,G10,C40,G40") to be copied to the next blank row on a separate worksheet

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy and paste multiple selections.  Quick and easy solution is to do one cell at a time.

```
Dim pasterange As Long
pasterange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' the plus 1 is to get the next blank row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Order Form").Range("B3").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders").Range("A" & pasterange)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Order Form").Range("F3").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders").Range("B" & pasterange)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Order Form").Range("C10").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders").Range("C" & pasterange)
```

I would just copy and paste that down and add the additional cells you need copied and continue the A,B,C, etc in the destination portion.

Comment: Thanks roses45 i will give it a try now :)

Comment: So close.. It works but i get #Ref in a lot of the boxes.... These boxes have formulas in them, i suppose that is why.. Hopefully the code just needs a slight amendment to copy the data correctly. Thanks roses45

Comment: Sorry, if there are formulas you can do the below instead.  Copy destination command does not work with pastespecial functions.  
```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders").Range("A" & pasterange) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Order Form").Range("B3").Value
```